# Cross evaluation of nodes with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to analyse the Input XML here below to tag a node `SENTENCE[SECONDARY]/TOKEN` with `FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY="YES"`, when its `BEGIN` value is greater than the `BEGIN` value of another `SENTENCE[SECONDARY]/TOKEN` in the same `PARAGRAPH` node.

Here below the input XML:

```
<DOCUMENT>
  <SECTION>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="0">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="14" END="25" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48"/>   
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEFORE_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="0" END="9" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>        
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN  BEGIN="43" END="47" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>       
       </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="27" END="34" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>          
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="1">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="2">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="37" END="41" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48"/> 
        <TOKEN BEGIN="37" END="41" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48"/>
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="43" END="47" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48"/> 
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="2">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="2">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="164" END="170" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187"/>          
        <TOKEN BEGIN="164" END="170" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187"/>         
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="172" END="175" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187"/>          
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="3">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="4">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="93" END="97" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133"/>   
        <TOKEN BEGIN="93" END="97" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133"/>         
        <TOKEN BEGIN="135" END="139" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187"/>
        <TOKEN BEGIN="135" END="139" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187"/>
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="141" END="147" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>        
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEFORE_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="79" END="88" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>          
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="3">
        <TOKEN  BEGIN="110" END="113" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>          
        <TOKEN  BEGIN="129" END="132" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>          
        <TOKEN  BEGIN="172" END="175" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>          
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="99" END="104" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/> 
        <TOKEN  BEGIN="153" END="158" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/> 
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="4">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="119" END="127" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133"/>
        </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="129" END="132" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133"/>       
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="5">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="50" END="58" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133"/>          
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="60" END="66" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133"/>   
       </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
  </SECTION>
</DOCUMENT>
```

This is the XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TOKEN[@SAME_SENTENCE][not (@BEFORE_PRIMARY)]">
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="((current()/@SENTENCE_BEGIN = ../../SENTENCE[@NAME='PRIMARY']/TOKEN/@SENTENCE_BEGIN) and (current()/@SENTENCE_END = ../../SENTENCE[@NAME='PRIMARY']/TOKEN/@SENTENCE_END)) and  (current()/@BEGIN &gt; ../../SENTENCE[@NAME='SECONDARY']/TOKEN [@SAME_SENTENCE] [not (@BEFORE_PRIMARY)]/@BEGIN)">

            <xsl:attribute name="FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY">YES</xsl:attribute>

      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This the Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DOCUMENT>
  <SECTION>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="0">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="14" END="25" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEFORE_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="0" END="9" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48" SAME_SENTENCE="YES" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="43" END="47" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48" SAME_SENTENCE="YES" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="27" END="34" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48" SAME_SENTENCE="YES" />
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="1">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="2">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="37" END="41" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="37" END="41" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="43" END="47" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48" />
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="2">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="2">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="164" END="170" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="164" END="170" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="172" END="175" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" />
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="3">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="4">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="93" END="97" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="93" END="97" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="135" END="139" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" />
        <TOKEN BEGIN="135" END="139" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="141" END="147" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" SAME_SENTENCE="YES" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEFORE_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="79" END="88" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" SAME_SENTENCE="YES" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="3">
        <TOKEN FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="110" END="113" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" SAME_SENTENCE="YES" />
        <TOKEN FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="129" END="132" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" SAME_SENTENCE="YES" />
        <TOKEN FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="172" END="175" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" SAME_SENTENCE="YES" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="99" END="104" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" SAME_SENTENCE="YES" />
        <TOKEN FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="153" END="158" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" SAME_SENTENCE="YES" />
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="4">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="119" END="127" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="129" END="132" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" />
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="5">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="50" END="58" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" />
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="60" END="66" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" />
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
  </SECTION>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Unfortunately, in the example above, the XSLT code, wrongly selects one of the `TOKENS`:

```
<SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
     <TOKEN FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="141" END="147" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>        
</SENTENCE>
```

Here below the complete desired Output:

```
<DOCUMENT>
  <SECTION>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="0">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="14" END="25" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48"/>   
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEFORE_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="0" END="9" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>        
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="43" END="47" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>       
       </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="27" END="34" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>          
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="1">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="2">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="37" END="41" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48"/> 
        <TOKEN BEGIN="37" END="41" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48"/>
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="43" END="47" SENTENCE_BEGIN="0" SENTENCE_END="48"/> 
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="2">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="2">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="164" END="170" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187"/>          
        <TOKEN BEGIN="164" END="170" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187"/>         
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="172" END="175" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187"/>          
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="3">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="4">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="93" END="97" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133"/>   
        <TOKEN BEGIN="93" END="97" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133"/>         
        <TOKEN BEGIN="135" END="139" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187"/>
        <TOKEN BEGIN="135" END="139" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187"/>
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="141" END="147" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>        
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEFORE_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="79" END="88" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>          
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="3">
        <TOKEN FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="110" END="113" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>          
        <TOKEN FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="129" END="132" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>          
        <TOKEN FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="172" END="175" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>          
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="99" END="104" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/> 
        <TOKEN FURTHER_FROM_PRIMARY="YES" BEGIN="153" END="158" SENTENCE_BEGIN="135" SENTENCE_END="187" SAME_SENTENCE="YES"/>   
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="4">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="119" END="127" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133"/>
        </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="129" END="132" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133"/>       
      </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
    <PARAGRAPH TRACK="5">
      <SENTENCE NAME="PRIMARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="50" END="58" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133"/>          
      </SENTENCE>
      <SENTENCE NAME="SECONDARY" COUNT="1">
        <TOKEN BEGIN="60" END="66" SENTENCE_BEGIN="50" SENTENCE_END="133"/>   
       </SENTENCE>
    </PARAGRAPH>
  </SECTION>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Do you have any clue on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention in your description that you also have some checks on `SENTENCE_BEGIN` and `SENTENCE_END` being the same too.

The problem is that your check of `BEGIN` is not dependent on the `SENTENCE_BEGIN` and `SENTENCE_END` being the same. In other words, you are testing "Is there a TOKEN with the same SENTENCE_BEGIN, and is there a token with the same SENTENCE_END, and is there a token with a lower BEGIN"

I think this is what you need....

```
<xsl:if test="../../SENTENCE[@NAME='SECONDARY']/TOKEN[@SENTENCE_BEGIN = current()/@SENTENCE_BEGIN and @SENTENCE_END = current()/@SENTENCE_END and not(@BEFORE_PRIMARY) and current()/@BEGIN &gt; @BEGIN]">
```

Comment: Thank  you! Yes, your are right sorry! I missed to add this requirement. I'm going to update the question